# Difference between code in JavaScript finally block and after try ... catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-finally

This question may appear similar to others that have been answered, but I can't find an answer relating to JavaScript.

**What is the difference between code in a finally block and code that comes after the *entire* try ... catch ... finally statement?**

That is, what is the difference between this code:

```js
try {
  f(x);
}
catch(e) {
  g(e);
}
finally {
  h(y);
}
```

and this code:

```js
try {
  f(x);
}
catch(e) {
  g(e);
}
h(y);
```

Comment: `finally` only makes a difference when using `return` or another `throw`. See [the spec](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-try-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and [the docs](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#description).

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+why+use+finally) of [Uses of the finally statement](/q/18251156/4642212).

Comment: Are you referring to the answer that @CertainPerformance gave?

Comment: _“Are you referring to the answer that @CertainPerformance gave?”_ — I’m not sure what you mean… Both my comments refer to your question.

Comment: Sorry—I meant to ask if you were making the same point that @CertainPerformance made in his answer.

Comment: Probably. What `finally` is used for is well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One difference is that, if a value is returned in a `finally`, it will override values returned from inside the prior `try` and `catch` blocks:

```js
function foo() {
  try {
    throw new Error('1');
  } catch(e) {
    return '2';
  } finally {
    return '3';
  }
}
console.log(foo());
```

Returning from a finally [will also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#returning_from_a_finally-block) prevent `throw`s in a `try` or `catch` from percolating outward - instead, only the `finally`'s normal return completion value will be the result.

```js
(function() {
  try {
    try {
      throw new Error('oops');
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error('inner', ex.message);
      throw ex;
    } finally {
      console.log('finally');
      return;
    }
  } catch (ex) {
    // not entered into
    console.error('outer', ex.message);
  }
})();
```

Comment: And, according to the duplicate question suggested by @SebastianSimon, any *other* code (not just `return` statements) in the finally block will run even if there is an error thrown or `return` in the `catch` block.

Comment: "will also result in throws in a try or catch from percolating outward"—do you mean that it will *prevent* them from percolating outward?

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit this question had me scratching my head at first.  But a look at the [MDN reference for `try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) includes this salient section on "[Returning from a finally-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#returning_from_a_finally-block)". It appears that if you `return` from a `finally` block, it will override anything returned or thrown from the preceding `try` or `catch` blocks.  So while your example may be identical, if you were to change it to this:

```js
try {
  return f(x);
}
catch(e) {
  throw g(e);
}
finally {
  return h(y);
}
```

...it would fundamentally differ from this:

```js
try {
  return f(x);
}
catch(e) {
  throw g(e);
}
return h(y);
```